# WPF. Команды в Datacontext

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

Есть viewmodel.

```
public class VM_searchResult : DependencyObject, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private CCard createdCard;    

    private Commands selectSpravInfo;
    public Commands SelectSpravInfo
    {
         get
         {
            return selectSpravInfo ?? (selectSpravInfo = new Commands(obj =>
              {
               W_selectSprav wSelectSprav = new W_selectSprav(obj as CCard);
               wSelectSprav.ShowDialog();
              }));
         }
    }
    public CCard CreatedCard
    {
        get { return createdCard; }
        set
        {
            createdCard = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("CreatedCard");
        }
    }
}
```

View

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" DataContext="{Binding CreatedCard}">
       <TextBlock Text="Номер регистрации:" Margin="10,7,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
       <TextBox x:Name="TB_regnum" Text="{Binding Regnum}" Margin="10,7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" MinWidth="90"/>
       <TextBlock Text="База данных:" Margin="10,7,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
       <Button x:Name="B_selectDB_card" Command="{Binding SelectSpravInfo}" CommandParameter="{Binding CreatedCard}" Content="..." Margin="10,7,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="20"/>
       <TextBox x:Name="TB_db_card" Text="{Binding Bdncpi._name}" Margin="10,7,15,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" IsEnabled="False" MinWidth="200"/>
</StackPanel>
```

В такой ситуации, команда `SelectSpravInfo` ищется в контексте `CreatedCard`, которой там, собственно нет. Отсюда вопрос, как выйти из этой ситуации? Не гоже как-то прописывать контекст каждому текстбоксу.

Comment: элементу у которого DataContext VM_searchResult дать имя, например  root. Дальше привязываетесь так: {Binding ElementName=root, Path=DataContext.SelectSpravInfo}

Comment: VM_searchResult есть контекст у самой вьюшки. Т.е.                   public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = new VM_searchResult();            
        }

Comment: во этой вью и дайте имя: x:Name="root"

Comment: Блеск! Сразу не понял о чем вы, но теперь разобрался. В итоге сделал так DataContext="{Binding ElementName=root}" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectSpravInfo}". Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @S.Kost: Почему бы тогда не оформить как ответ?

Comment: @VladD, У меня был ответ на подобный вопрос, но я не смог его найти. В общем ответил еще раз.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Даем имя элементу у которого DataContext `VM_searchResult` (там где лежит команда к которой нужно привязаться). Дальше биндим нужное свойство через `ElementName`

```
<UserControl x:Name="root"> <!--DataContext устанавливается например сверху -->
    <StackPanel DataContext="{Binding CreatedCard}">    
        <Button Command="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=DataContext.SelectSpravInfo}" CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=root, Path=DataContext.CreatedCard}"/>      
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

Решение. Дал имя вьюшке `x:Name="root"` и потом использовал его как 
`DataContext="{Binding ElementName=root}" Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.SelectSpravInfo}"`